# Dynamically add Grand total row

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a table that contains cell that does not give me numbers sometimes.
E.g

```
Country     16/7/12     13/4/14     12/12/12
Singapore      1           3           5
Myanmar        5                       2
```

I have been trying to add a total on the bottom which will come out like this

```
Country     16/7/12     13/4/14     12/12/12
Singapore      1           3           5
Myanmar        5                       2
Total          6           3           7
```

However i have not been able to do so. im using vb and ms access to do a windows form.

```
Dim Total As Integer() = New Integer(DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1) {}
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
            If cell.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
            Else
                Total(cell.ColumnIndex) = Total(cell.ColumnIndex) +       DataGridView1.Rows(cell.RowIndex).Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).Value
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

This is what ive tried. I am trying to pull all the value from each column, intending to append them to an array.

Because mine is a crosstab query thus it must be dynamically built.

I had faced things such as null is being returned or something cause im using sql Count function and by right it should return me an integer.

Please help me thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why don't you get the value directly from cell?
Also try to add a check on that value (If cell.Value <> Nothing And cell.Value <> '')Then Total(cell.ColumnIndex) ...etc...etc..

Comment: Hi Thanks x 100 for your reply i need it to incorporate with some pdf churning functions.